# How to Recognise which menuItem is disabled?

Tags: java, android, menu, toolbar, menuitem

Heyy,

I have implemented menu, where there are two menu items and when I click on first item, the other menu item goes disabled and vise-versa.

And when I click on back button navigation icon, I have to check if first item is disabled or not and if disabled, then turn the second item enabled, and if not then `onBackPressed();`

So, I don't know how to recognize which item is disabled.

Please help me fast.

There are some code references

This is my current try and it also have some errors. Please help me find another way or fix this code.

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (menu.getItem(0).getActionView().getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    onBackPressed();
                } else {
                    menu.getItem(1).setEnabled(false);
                    menu.getItem(1).setVisible(false);

                    menu.getItem(0).setEnabled(true);
                    menu.getItem(0).setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: plz provide more code.. how do you get `menu` var .. is it from `onCreateOptionsMenu()`?

Comment: yes, it is from onCreateOptionsMenu()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` store the `menu` into a local class field, and then to check if a certain menu item is enabled/disabled use `isEnabled()`

```
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.item_id);
if (item.isEnabled()) {
    // enabled
} else {
    // not enabled 
}
```

Or you can use the order of the item among the menu items to get a particular item

```
MenuItem item = menu.getItem(0);
```